# How to set multiple environment variables with cabal/haskell?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am making use of [`postgresql-typed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-typed-0.6.2.2/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Typed.html) library which needs multiple environment variables to be set before it runs.

Right now, I am manually setting them using the shell profile script (zsh profile) before I can run any of the cabal commands like `cabal build` or `cabal run`.

But this is clumsy and doesn't work across all the platforms. Is there a idiomatic Haskell/Cabal way of doing this (For example, adding them from `.env` file or something)?

Comment: `direnv` https://direnv.net/ is a useful (not cabal-related)  tool that automatically sets variables when you enter a folder. It doesn't work on Windows, however.

Comment: Can you follow the documented advice, and use `useTPGDatabase` to avoid needing to consult environment variables in the first place?

Comment: @DanielWagner I tried using `useTPGDatabase` but I keep getting the error - `user error (pgGetMessage: unsupported authentication type: 10)`.

Comment: @HarshalPatil Could you put together a minimal reproducing example of that?

Comment: So, after some debugging I found out that `postgresql-typed` doesn't work well with postgres 14 or 15 docker image. It works perfectly fine with native postgres installation. It looks like something's different between the two.
However, the original question is still not fully answered. Need way to setup multiple environment variables via cabal or equivalent to comply with 12-factor app.

Comment: @DanielWagner I am now using `useTPGDatabase` for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, cabal does not have a generalized tool for mucking about with environment variables. In my opinion, this is good design, of the "do one thing and do it well" variety -- there are already good external tools for setting up environment variables, some of which are quite large and complicated, and duplicating that work inside cabal is not called for.

Cabal does set a few environment variables on your behalf, but only those an external tool has no way to set properly, such as file system pointers to intermediate build products or intended installation directories.